# MVVM Model vs. DDD Entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, mvvm, domain-model, entity

I have just stepped into the Domain Driven Design paradigm but I have one question:

How is an MVVM Model different from a DDD Entity? What are the differences between these two?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, do you mean both Model and Entity should be handled separately? The reason why i put up this question, I am using my entities as Model currently. Both are same.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Model–view–viewmodel (MVVM)** is a software architectural pattern that separates the development of the graphical user interface from the development of the business logic or back-end logic.

A **DDD Entity** is something that *has identity and type in a business context.*  For example, airline seats are entities; the airline treats them all the same way (subject to first-class, etc.)  However, each seat is an *instance* with its own identity.

If you were to combine MVVM with Domain-Driven Design, the DDD Entities would become part of the MVVM's **Model**  (*but not the ViewModel*). For example:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class AirlineSeat
    {
        // implementation of DDD Entity
    }

    public class FrequentFlyer: Flyer, Person
    {
        // Another DDD Entity
    }
}
```

**Further Reading**
[Model–view–viewmodel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)
[Domain-Driven Design: Building Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Building_blocks)

Comment: "If you were to combine MVVM with Domain-Driven Design, the DDD Entities would become part of the MVVM's Model." Can you please explain it further with example.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Is AirlineSeat is acting as an Entity and Model at the same time? My confusion is whether they are two different things or one thing with two different names?

Comment: AirlineSeat is *part* of the model.  Think of it this way: none of your DDD stuff is going to go into the View or Controller of MVVM, unless you're referring to it from the model, where it originates.

Comment: So you mean Model is the place where you can expose your DDD Entity? However both are two separate things, correct?

Comment: Keep in mind that DDD is just a design technique, and so is MVVM.  The way those two design techniques interact is that your DDD Entities become *part of the Model* in MVVM.  In fact, all of DDD can fit into the Model, essentially.

Comment: Think, I have got your point here. Both are same things with two different names.

Comment: Not the same thing.  You can use any technique you want to create the Model, not just DDD.  You can use ActiveRecord, for example.  Conversely, you can use any suitable technology you want to implement DDD Entities, though domain classes seem to be the preferred way.

Comment: I know every design has its own way of modeling things but in this case DDD entity can also act as a Model for MVVM. Correct?

Comment: It would be more correct to say that the DDD Entities would be *part of the Model* in MVVM.  You can, and will, have other things in the model besides DDD Entities.

Comment: Thanks now i have a better understanding. Can you please update your answer to include discussed stuff to make it more clear. Making a sample Model using Entities part of it.

Comment: The "View Model" in MVVM is really a kind of Controller. It would be a much easier to follow your answer if you mentioned the differing uses of the word "Model".

Comment: @RubberDuck: I added a clarification, though note that the ViewModel in MVVM and the Controller in MVC are quite different, and have different purposes.  The ViewModel substitutes for the Controller, but that doesn't mean they do the same things.